# Kerberos Authentication NGINX in Linux Environment returns 403 Unauthorized

Tags: nginx, kerberos, http-status-code-403, spnego

I'm trying to setup an **nginx server (1.19.0)** on **Ubuntu (18.04)** which uses current version of **[spnego-http-auth-nginx-module](https://github.com/stnoonan/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module)**.

I successfully built nginx with spnego module, and it works as expected without auth_gss enabled.

I set up my keytab file as stated in [ifad's fork](https://github.com/ifad/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module/blob/master/README.md).

With this keytab file, when I run command

```
kinit -5 -V -k -t /usr/local/nginx/krb5.keytab HTTP/deneme.aaa.com
```

I successfuly get the message

```
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_1000
Using principal: HTTP/deneme.aaa.com@DOMAIN.COM.TR
Using keytab: krb5.keytab
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
```

and klist -k krb5.keytab command shows

```
Keytab name: FILE:krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4 host/deneme.aaa.com@DOMAIN.COM.TR
   6 HTTP/deneme.aaa.com@DOMAIN.COM.TR
```

```
user  root root;                                             
worker_processes  1;                                         
                                                             
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;                                  
                                                             
events {                                                     
    worker_connections  1024;                                
}                                                            
                                                             
http {                                                       
    include       mime.types;                                
    default_type  application/octet-stream;                  
                                                             
    sendfile        on;                                      
                                                             
    # HTTPS server                                           
    #                                                        
    server {                                                 
        listen       443 ssl;                                
        server_name  deneme.aaa.com;              
                                                             
        ssl_certificate      /home/user/public.crt;  
        ssl_certificate_key  /home/user/private.rsa; 
                                                             
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;                  
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;                             
                                                             
        location / {                                         
            root   html;                                     
            index  index.html index.htm;                     
            auth_gss on;                                     
            auth_gss_allow_basic_fallback off;               
        }                                                    
    }                                                        
}
```

With the configuration above, when I hit the page https://deneme.aaa.com, I get 403 unauthorized error withput any login prompt. There's no logs in logs/error.log. In the access.log

```
192.168.106.1 - - [24/Jun/2020:11:26:29 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 581 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
192.168.106.1 - - [24/Jun/2020:11:26:29 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
```

When I make

```
auth_gss_allow_basic_fallback on;
```

login prompt appears and with the correct credentials I can access the index page, but this is because basic authentication works.

When I hit the page from browser and run klist on the client machine I can see the Kerberos tickets are issued.

What could be the reason? Should I use the older version of nginx?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keytab file includes principals created with **AES256-SHA1** encryption. However I forgot to check **This account supports kerberos aes256 bit encryption** checkbox in the Active Directory Users and Computers. So Clients were trying to send **RC4-HMAC** encrypted Kerberos tickets to NGINX.

Checking this option solved the problem.

Hope this helps.